# NGINX Long Lived Connection - Scaling Out/In Issue

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, high-availability

we have following architecture where Local market data center is trying to connect to NGINX through AWS Network Load balancer.

[image]

we have defined following alive timeout at NGINX level:

```
keepalive_timeout 75s;keepalive_requests 100;
```

I have following question on above architecture:

1. After establishing  TCP connection 1.1 (Left to Right) if NGINX#1 pods gets terminated due to some reason (within keep alive timeout), will TCP connection get terminated as well or same TCP connection will be used and choose new available pod.
2. In case of Scale-out (Pod 5) or scale-in scenario , how connection will be distributed or load balance between available pods for long-lived TCP connection.

Thanks in advance.